# Para qué se usa la barra vertical "|" en Java

Tags: java, operador

tengo una duda pequeña con este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a =  1; 
boolean  b =  false; 
if (a  <  0  |  b ==  true){ 
    System.out.println("true"); 
}
else { 
    System.out.println("false"); 
}
```

}

Si le creo entender pero, qué indica la barra vertical que se sitúa antes de la b?, es un "Or"?

Comment: Aqui tienes la respuesta https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mas común es utilizar la doble barra vertical `||` que seria un `OR`, pero también es permitido utilizar la sola `|` la diferencia es que si tenemos el caso que la primera condición es `true` con doble barra se evalúa la primera parte y no se evalúa la segunda porque aunque sea `false` el resultado final será `true || false = true` y si es con una barra el resultado no varia pero se ejecutarían las 2 comprobaciones:

```
public class PruebaOr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;

        // El valor true en la primera comprobación NO ejecuta la segunda
        if (i == 2 || i++ == 3){
            // Imprime 2 porque no se ejecuta la segunda comprobación
            System.out.println( "Or ||  = " + i);
        }
        // El valor true en la primera comprobación ejecuta la segunda
        // suma uno a la variable y comprueba que sea 3
        if (i == 2 | i++ == 3 ){
            // Imprime 3
            System.out.println( "Or |  = " + i);;
        }
    }
}
```